# Add entries to ArrayList in HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I have an ArrayList with some entries as a value in a HashMap, how to add new values to it?

Thanks.Did it like this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> index = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
void add(String kword, String... urls){
    if(index.containsKey(kword)){
        index.get(kword).addAll(Arrays.asList(urls));
    } else {
        index.put(kword, (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(urls));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code? You need to show it to us to get the desired answer, please.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Uh... your code will break if `Arrays.asList()` does not use an `ArrayList` for its result...

Comment: ..not to mention that creating a list from an array just to be able to use `List.addAll()` is very good way to hurt the performance of any application.

Comment: Better to change to String[]?

Comment: @JohnGray: from a performance standpoint you would be better off using `List.add()` in an explicit loop as I did in my answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have something along these lines:

```
Map<K, ArrayList<V>> map = new HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>>();
```

then this should allow you to add new values to any list that is contained as a value in the map:

```
map.get(listKey).add(newValue);
```

Naturally, you can also store the result of `map.get(listKey)` to a temporary variable to avoid the cost of `map.get()` when inserting multiple values:

```
List<V> list = map.get(listKey);

for (V value : newValues)
    list.add(value);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an iterrator for such cases?

Comment: @JohnGray: 1. An iterator to do what? 2. The snippet with the loop already uses an iterator internally if `newValues` is a `Collection`...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on exactly what values you want to add from your [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Is it the entries, keys or values? You can iterate over either entries, keys or values on the map and add the ones you want into your list.

The example below gets the entries from the map, using [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method in HashMap. It assumes you have a method to check if the entry is the one you are looking for (`isThisTheEntryIAmLookingFor(...)`).

```
Map<String, String> map;
//...

ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = 
        new ArrayList<Entry<String, String>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {

    if (isThisTheEntryIAmLookingFor(e)) {

        list.add(e);

    }

}
```

If you just want to gather keys or values, use the [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) or [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) respectively, with the correct types.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have an `ArrayList<String>`, do it like this:

```
List<String> l = map.get("your_key");
l.add("Some Other Value");
```

It's fairly easy to use this code snippet with a list of other than `String` instances. Just use the proper generic.

Answer (score 0):

You might find your life made significantly easier with [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`Multimap` type](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) -- specifically [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) -- which takes care of all this nonsense for you.